# What font type was used in "Kevin O'Malley" found at the bottom of the cover of the How They Croaked book?

Tags: font-identification, book

At the bottom-right of the cover of [this](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8ZKAtLkNAksC) book, it shows the Illustrator's name like this:

[image: Bottom of How They Croaked at right]

I found a similar font to this called [ITC Anima Black](http://www.fonts.com/font/itc/itc-anima/black), and it looks like this:

[image: ITC Anima Black]

Unfortunately, this font isn't free. Is there a similar font to this for web use that is free?

Comment: I used your image above on whatthefont.com (on myfonts.com). <a href="http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/results?ch%5B0%5D=K&ch%5B1%5D=E&ch%5B2%5D=V&ch%5B3%5D=I&ch%5B4%5D=N&ch%5B5%5D=O&ch%5B6%5D=%27&ch%5B7%5D=M&ch%5B8%5D=A&ch%5B9%5D=L&ch%5B10%5D=L&ch%5B11%5D=E&ch%5B12%5D=Y&wtfserver=wtf_b_41&id=00149d17539f05bd000e7fbb00005b8a&glyphcount=13&imageid=0&x=56&y=46">Results here.</a> With a larger screen shot it may be possible to get an exact match. But it still may be a font you would have to buy. I would check out <a href="http://dafont.com">dafont.com</a> for 'crafty' fonts like these. Most all

Answer (score 1):

I like this [Altogether](http://www.linotype.com/432389/CCAltogetherOoky-product.html) font match:

[image]

You can find it for free, but illegal.. so find it yourself.

Comment: Why are you suggesting I do something illegal? I said that a free alternative is what I'm looking for, but +1 for finding an exact match.

Comment: @I don't suggest, I mean - I don't provide a link to any "free" copy of this font...

Answer (score 0):

That [Altogether](http://www.linotype.com/432389/CCAltogetherOoky-product.html) font from Ilan's answer led me to find the Adam's font family which led me to a font that looks exactly like the Altogether font: [Adam's Regular](http://www.ffonts.net/AddamsRegular.font).